# does DLNA support 4K resolution video?

Tags: dlna

Does DNLA support 4K resolution video?

If yes, which version of DLNA is it?

My Sony Bravia tv set doesn`t support 4K playback through DLNA i.e. from NAS server.

I can only play such file from USB hard drive.

Answer (score 2):

DLNA does not specify how the content should be packaged or encoded. It only provides means for accessing media databases and retrieving objects from them. As such, it’s completely dependent on the actual devices whether they can play some movie or not.

**Bottom line: DLNA isn’t at fault.**

Your TV might have been made with stability in mind: Low-quality wireless networks might not be able to keep up with 4K bitrates. Because complaining customers are bad, they just disabled it outright.

Sometimes, non-PC devices also have strange limitations on data flow. The TV’s (wireless) network adapter might not be able to pump its data to the HEVC decoder chip in an efficient manner.

Answer (score 1):

I see this is an old question, but posting my latest experience, in case it is of help to somebody. I have an LG C8 OLED. I have connected by external HDD to my Netgear AX8 router. The router exposes the HDD content via DLNA, and my TV is able to connect to that server. My TV is connected to my network over Wifi, and I can stream 4K content, with HDR and 5.1 audio with no issues.

Answer (score 0):

i have the same problem on my LG tv, only play over USB. THough i use wired connection between media server and the TV. I have contacted LG in this regard, their response was that WEB OS 2.0 does not support 4k streaming over dlna, however, it will be supported on Web OS 3.0

As such - you *could* stream 4k over DNLA but its device and firmware version dependant.

Comment: I'm trying to choose the TV now.
LG support team keeps saying that 'DLNA does not support 4k'. Web OS 3.0 and Web OS 3.5 devices are issued.

Samsung support says their devices work with 4k via DLNA. Needs to be checked on physical device.